# Python script to find files that contain a text string

Tags: python

Python script to find files that contain a text string

I want to find a text file that contains particular string.

The below is not finding the matching file name and the matching line number.

```
import os

search_path = "C:\\Users\\xx\\Desktop\\text_file\\" #folder to search
file_type = ".txt" #filetype to search
search_str = " INTERIM BILL-SUMMARY" #string to search

if not (search_path.endswith("/") or search_path.endswith("\\") ): # Append a directory separator if not already present
        search_path = search_path + "/"                                                         
if not os.path.exists(search_path):  # If path does not exist, set search path to current directory
        search_path ="."
for fname in os.listdir(path=search_path): # Repeat for each file in the directory 
   if fname.endswith(file_type):  # Apply file type filter  
        fo = open(search_path + fname) # Open file for reading
        line = fo.readline() # Read the first line from the file
        line_no = 1 # Initialize counter for line number
        while line != '' :   # Loop until EOF
                index = line.find(search_str) # Search for string in line
                if ( index != -1) :
                    print(fname, "[", line_no, ",", index, "] ", line, sep="")           
                line = fo.readline()  # Read next line
                line_no += 1 # Increment line counter
        fo.close() # Close the files
```

Comment: your `search_str` is `" INTERIM BILL-SUMMARY"`, maybe remove the extra space from the start of the string and try again? Also, make sure that your file contents are all capitalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you please try this, and tell me if it works for you?

```py
import os

search_path = "C:\\Users\\xx\\Desktop\\text_file\\" #folder to search
file_type = ".txt" #filetype to search
search_str = "INTERIM BILL-SUMMARY" #string to search

if not (search_path.endswith("/") or search_path.endswith("\\") ): # Append a directory separator if not already present
        search_path = search_path + "/"                                                         
if not os.path.exists(search_path):  # If path does not exist, set search path to current directory
        search_path ="."
for fname in os.listdir(path=search_path): # Repeat for each file in the directory 
   if fname.endswith(file_type):  # Apply file type filter  
        with open(search_path + fname) as f: # Open file for reading
            for line_no, line in enumerate(f):
                if search_str in line:
                    print(fname, "[", line_no, ",", line.find(search_str), "] ", line, sep="")
```

Comment: BTW, I couldn't spot any problem with your original, I just rewrote a small part and checked locally on some dummy files, seems to work for me

Answer (score 0):

I just found this post by accident :) and modified some lines for better handling and csv output !

```
import os
import csv

search_path = input("Enter directory path to search : ")
file_type = input("File Type : ")
search_str = input("Enter the search string : ")

if not (search_path.endswith("/") or search_path.endswith("\\") ): # Append a directory separator if not already present
        search_path = search_path + "/"                                                         
if not os.path.exists(search_path):  # If path does not exist, set search path to current directory
        search_path ="."
for fname in os.listdir(path=search_path): # Repeat for each file in the directory 
   if fname.endswith(file_type):  # Apply file type filter  
        with open(search_path + fname,encoding="utf-8") as f: # Open file for reading
            with open('output.csv', 'a+') as output:
            #csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
                for line_no, line in enumerate(f):
                    if search_str in line:
                        output.write("".join(map(str, [line])))
                        print(fname, "[", line_no, ",", line.find(search_str), "] ", line, sep="")
```